# How do I constrain an angle from rotating in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

I have a gun and a player. I want to constrain the angle of the gun so the player doesn't raise his gun up too much or too low. The player and gun turns to the right side when the mouse is facing the right, and if the mouse faces the left, the player and gun turns to the left. I want to constrain the gun between 160 and -160 when it faces right. And constrain the gun between 20 and -20 when it faces left. So it doesn't rotate over the constraining restriction.

I have a code that makes it rotate 360, but I'm not sure on how to stop it from rotating once it reaches a certain point.

```
        if (parent != null)
        {
            var dx = MovieClip(parent).crosshair.x - x;
            var dy = MovieClip(parent).crosshair.y - y;
            var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)/Math.PI * 180;
            rotation = angle;
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean 60 to -60 when it faced right? 160 to -160 gives a 320 range. You can't do it when facing right, because at some point you will start facing left,

Comment: Sorry I get a little bit confused with the rotation cycle.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this though? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to "stop" it literally. Just calculate the angle as you do and check it against the limits. I don't remember how AS3 angle values correspond to directions, but let's assume for example that right direction is from 0 to 180. So, if your angle is within (0..180), you're facing right.  Now, for this range your limits should be 30 and 150. You do: `if (angle < 30) angle = 30; if (angle > 150) angle = 150;`. And similar thing for the left direction.

Comment: It's strange, it doesn't work for the left. I tried switching the code you gave me for, the <, I switched to >. and for the second code, I switched the > to <. Then now if I try it, the gun just freezes in one spot.

Comment: For left, you have to use different limits, not only switching "<" and ">". I can't check what these limits will be, you have to check it yourself, just trace the angle value when facing left and see what limits it has. Basically you need a value that corresponds the strictly left direction and then just add 60 and subtract 60 to that value to get upper and lower limit. Your angle then should be checked to be no less than lower value and no higher than upper value.

Comment: After losing a few brain cells thinking, I found it out. if (rotation > -120 && rotation < 0) rotation = -120;. Please tell me if there are more ways! Thanks! This was my way of doing it.

Comment: But do you know how I could make it change every time I put my mouse over the left or right side? I've tried if (mouse > x) and if (mouse < x) but it only worked for one side and the other side freezed.

Comment: I checked and there is a difference between calculated value and the real rotation value. Needs some special treatment, I'll be back with the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what's happening:

Flash rotation at 0° faces strictly up. So the right side will be from 0° to 180° and left side will be from 0° to -180°. This is easy to separate because all right side > 0 and all left side < 0.

But, Math.atan2(dy, dx) calculates a different angle which cannot be directly assigned to object rotation. Instead of left and right side, it is < 0 on upper side and > 0 on lower side. If you calculate the rotation that way, it will be a mess.

So, the atan calculation must be shifted by 90° clockwise in order to match the Flash rotation. This is done by transforming the parameters and now it looks like Math.atan2(dx, -dy). After that the calculated angle and the rotation angle will match.

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dx, -dy) / Math.PI * 180;

if (angle < 0) { // facing left
    if (angle > -30) angle = -30;
    if (angle < -150) angle = -150;
} else { // facing right
    if (angle < 30) angle = 30;
    if (angle > 150) angle = 150;
}
```

This is the solution without using -dy and instead using dy. (Code added by OP and I didn't check it :)

```
var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI * 180;
if (rotation > -180 && rotation < -90 || rotation > 90 && rotation < 180 )
{ // facing left
    if (rotation > -150 && rotation < 0) 
    {
        rotation = -150;
    }
    if (rotation < 120 && rotation > 0) 
    {
        rotation = 120;
    }
}
else
{
    { // facing right
    if (rotation < -30) 
    {
        rotation = -30;
    }
    if (rotation > 60) 
    {
        rotation = 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my bullet and gun need to be turned 90 degrees, it's complicated. Is there another way to do it without having to turn everything 90 degrees thanks.

Comment: Oh wait, I actually just used the regular rotation. I'll add my code to yours.

Comment: I've been trying to find this solution for a long time. Not many people use this code. So, it was hard to find a way. You helped me a lot. Thanks :)